# Why does mathematical operation in SQL return 0

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, math

Why is the `CALC` value not calculated in the TSQL query below?

```
SELECT
    D1, D2, (D1+D2) As 'Sum', ((D1/(D1+D2))*100) As CALC
FROM
    (SELECT 3 As D1, 6 As D2) A
```

This is the result I get:

```
D1          D2          Sum         CALC
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
3           6           9           0
```

Comment: What datatype are D1 and D2?  I guess some integral type....

Comment: Actually in this example everything should work :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/12066 but I guess you have different types in the real example.

Comment: @outcoldman actually, I'm in SQL-server which I updated in the tags

Comment: A trick I've kind of picked up is to multiply as many values in the numerator as possible before dividing. That or adding 0.0 or multiplying by 1.0 to some constant to get the parser to not use integer division. Even "SELECT 3.0 AS D1" would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer division was rounding to zero
Move the 100.  You will still get some rounding.
If you cannot tolerate any rounding then don't use integers.

```
SELECT
    D1, D2, (D1+D2) As 'Sum', D1/(D1+D2) as frac, (D1*100)/(D1+D2) As pct
FROM
    (SELECT 3 As D1, 6 As D2) A
```

Answer (score 2):

integer divided by integer generates an integer, so if the operands are both integers your division operation will truncate the fractional portion of the result.  Change one to a float or to a decimal to fix it.

run  `Select 5 / 6,   5 / 6.0` to see what I mean

Fix your code with a cast...

```
 SELECT  D1, D2, (D1+D2) As 'Sum', 
    ((D1/ Cast(D1+D2 as Float))*100) As CALC
 FROM (SELECT 3 As D1, 6 As D2) A
```

or just make the values floats to start off with:

```
 SELECT  D1, D2, (D1+D2) As 'Sum', 
    ((D1/ (D1+D2))*100) As CALC
 FROM (SELECT 3.0 As D1, 6.0 As D2) A
```